# pyinstaller error when make .exe ; json not found

Tags: python, json, package, pyinstaller

I use VS code and python for making some tool for work.
And I put my py file and json file in the same directory.
C:\Users\username

And I do the  on VS code, it works well.
However, whenever I run the pyinstaller for packaging.
I got the message below.

C:\Users\username>pyinstaller --onefile --icon=xross.ico --noconsole --hidden-import babel.numbers　--add-data "C:\Users\username\cs-new-success-c50837cb5b30.json;./" xrosscustomer01.py

374 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.5

374 INFO: Python: 3.10.7

383 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0

384 INFO: wrote C:\Users\username.spec

387 INFO: UPX is not available.

script 'C:\Users\username\cs-new-success-c50837cb5b30.json;.' not found

Well, sorry for disturb, but what can I do more for solving it?

I added these codes for it.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        resource_path('cs-new-success-c50837cb5b30.json'), scope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

And added these too.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
]

json_key_path = "./cs-new-success-c50837cb5b30.json" # JSON Key File Path

json_file_name = 'cs-new-success-c50837cb5b30.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file_name, scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

But it did not work too, I got same result.

Comment: `script 'C:\Users\username\cs-new-success-c50837cb5b30.json;.' not found` Is the location of this file correct

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Yes, I put my all files(py , json , spec)in the same directory, C:\Users\username .